# Convert IP2Location Decimals to IP

Tags: postgresql, go, ip2location

IP ranges in the ip2location database are represented by first and last IPs as integers.

I don't know how the conversion from IPs to integers is done, but [documentation](https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/importing-ip2location-data-into-postgresql-and-querying-with-php-ipv6/) indicates it is equivalent to this code in PHP:

```php
function ip62long($ipv6) {
  return (string) gmp_import(inet_pton($ipv6));
}
```

If it's a IPv4 (not IPv6), the IP is prepended with `'::ffff:'`.

I'm trying to import ip2location database into postgres using the column type `INET`. I would want to convert these integers back to IPs, i.e. revert this routine.

So far I'm using this code:

```golang
func StringToIp(in string) net.IP {
    var bigint big.Int
    bigint.SetString(in, 10)
    return bigint.Bytes()
}
```

That works fine for:

- IPv6 addresses, e.g. `55838750788714571402502155597250560000` -> `2a02:26f7:e5c4:c6c1::`

and would work in theory for

- IPv4 addresses (without the `::ffff:` prefix), e.g. `16909060` -> `1.2.3.4`

But it does not work for these case:

- All IPv4 prefixed with `::ffff:`, e.g. `281470681743360` should become `0.0.0.0` instead of `?ffff00000000`.
- Cases like `0`, `281470681743359`, `281474439839744`, `281474976710656`.

I'm looking for a solution to convert all these values back to IPv4 or IPv6 addresses respectively to store them in postgres and look up IPs later on.

Comment: You should edit the question and add a description of the format produced by `ip62long()`. I am not interested in hunting it down by following the links.

Comment: There is no documentation available for `ip62long()`. `gmp_import` and `inet_pton` are builtin functions of PHP.

Comment: PHP is open source, isn't it? Make it easy for the people who are willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem seems to be that `bigint.Bytes()` returns less than 16 Bytes if the integer doesn't need it, while `net.IP` expects either 4 or 16 Bytes.

Prepending the `[]byte` up with enough zeros results in proper `net.IP`:

```golang
func StringToIp(in string) net.IP {
    var bigint big.Int
    bigint.SetString(in, 10)
    ip := bigint.Bytes()

    for len(ip) < 16 {
        ip = append([]byte{0x00}, ip...)
    }

    return ip
}
```

Happy to see and accept other, more elegant, ... solutions.